# How to add a scrollbar to JPanel

Tags: jpanel, jscrollbar

Hello guys i am having some trouble adding a scroll-bar to an application i wrote. As i have a 17 inch monitor i have no need for it but the other people have tried on smaller screens and couldn't access some items on the GUI. I thought about adding a scroll-bar but i am having difficulties. How would i add a scroll-bar to a JPanel i currently have. What it should do: If people re-size the window then it has they have to be able to scroll to the bottom, here is what i have but it doesn't work :s

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 753, 852);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    scrollPane= new JScrollPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(contentPane.getWidth(),contentPane.getHeight()));
    getContentPane().add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    then i got alot of contantPane.add()...
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is how you are adding all of the components into the `contentPane` after you have already added it to the `getContentPane()` pane. Try adding all of the components to the `contentPane` *before* you dad the `contentPane` to the main content pane, if that makes sense.. I think that may be your problem.